# How to pull a formula off a sheet and adding "=" to the front to run

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, copy-paste

I'm trying to set up a log and have a concatenate formula to combine a few columns but everytime I run it I get a #NA because VBA/Excel is adding extra characters in my formula for some reason. Any better way to copy and paste my formula with a "=" in the front of it? The goal here is to copy and paste over these formulas as values to remove the formula afterwards.

I tried selecting where I wanted to start the pasting and just do a 'activecell.formulaR1C1' by adding a "=" in front of it but that is when I am getting the extra ' inside my formula for some reason?

my equation:

```
CONCATENATE('Data'!J2," ",'Data'!K2," From ",'Data'!H2) {this is what is in worksheet("calculation") Cell: C2}
```

code:

```
Worksheets("Calculations").Range("C2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Log").Range("B2")
    Range("B2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & ActiveCell.Formula
```

I'm hoping to be able to get it pasted as the formula and to add one more line to copy and paste over the formula as just a .value

Comment: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & Replace(ActiveCell.Formula,"""","""""")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
With Sheets("Log").Range("B2")
    Worksheets("Calculations").Range("C2").Copy .Cells(1)
    .Formula = "=" & .Value
End with
```

If you don't really need the `Copy` then:

```
Sheets("Log").Range("B2").Formula = "=" & Worksheets("Calculations").Range("C2").Value
```